# Define a variable for use outside of the scope

Tags: c

Am trying to help out by modifying a piece of code and I fear I am falling foul of "When you define a variable, you can only use it within the defined scope."

Trying to implement language change by way of text strings as opposed to duplicating code.  So I would like to literally be able to say...

```
if (language == 0)
{
static const XCHAR text1[] = ("HELLO");
} else {
static const XCHAR text1[] = ("BONJOUR");
}
```

Then to be able to use within the code...

```
StCreate
(
ID_ST31,
 20,
 82,
 780,
 500,
 ST_DRAW,
 text1,
 alt3Scheme
);
```

From what I have read here, the above code will only initialize the text field within the {}?  Do I need to set the variable to NULL outside?Please tell me I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Yes, but there's a `static` and that carry a significance, no?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why not do the things properly from the start?

Comment: Why can't it just be a pointer to a `const char` pointer that's defined in a higher scope, and initialized by the branch? What does a const array give you?

Comment: This eventually wil become a nightmare of maintenance. Use a global array and an access-function to return the string from index (parameter)/language (variable).

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a pointer with ternary operator:

```
const char* text1 = (language == 0) ? "HELLO" : "BONJOUR";
```

In general, such problems are solved with pointers, like this:

```
const struct my_struct* actual_data;
if (cond) {
    static const struct my_struct data = {...};
    actual_data = data;
} else {
    static const struct my_struct data = {...};
    actual_data = data;
}
```

But personally I don't see any point in using arrays for strings in such trivial case if you don't need to modify them.

> Do I need to set the variable to NULL outside?

It's not necessary but often considered as good practice.

For your particular case there's very simple and relatively scalable way to make localization - use arrays:

```
static const char* const text1[LANGUAGE_COUNT] = {
    "HELLO",
    "BONJOUR",
    "ПРИВЕТ",
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You basicly want this:

```
static const XCHAR *text1_ENG = "HELLO";
static const XCHAR *text1_FRA = "BONJOUR";

char *GetText1()
{
   if (language == 0)
     return text1_ENG;
   else
     return text1_FRA;
}
...
StCreate
(
ID_ST31,
 20,
 82,
 780,
 500,
 ST_DRAW,
 GetText1(),
 alt3Scheme
);
```

But there is still a lot of room for improvement here. You probably have more that one text in your program and you also may have more than two languages.

Answer (score -1):

You need to know whether you actually want the declaration the be `static`. If you have only one file for your project, you can declare everything static within that file, but if you want visibility between files you can't declare a variable as static and have it known, it will not be visible from other files.

Comment: That doesn't provide an answer, it belongs in the comments to the OP.